# Browsing and Uploading a file to database using asp.net and sql server

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I am trying to browse for a file and then save the chosen file to a sql server database. Unfortunately I am not able to save the file.
Please advise. Thank you.

My C# asp.net code:

```
namespace WebApplication1{
public partial class uploadFiles : System.Web.UI.Page{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void btnUpload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
        {
            try
            {
                string filename = Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);
                Stream strm = FileUpload1.PostedFile.InputStream;
                BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(strm);
                Byte[] filesize = br.ReadBytes((int)strm.Length);
                string filetype = FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentType;

                SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=LAPTOP-K5AQHLFS\\SQLSERVER;Initial Catalog=uploadFiles;Integrated Security=True");
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
                cmd.CommandText = "insert into tb_uploadedFiles(Name,Type,Data)value(@Name,@Type,@Data)";
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", filename);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Type", filetype);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Data", filesize);
                cmd.Connection = con;
                con.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                con.Close();
                lblProg.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
                lblProg.Text = "Saved successfully";
            }
            catch
            {
                lblProg.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
                lblProg.Text = "File not saved";
            }
        }
        else
        {
            lblProg.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
            lblProg.Text = "select file first";
        }
    }
}
}
```

My Sql Server database :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/83tMp.png)

Comment: You should always include any relevant error messages you get in your question. I realize you're not seeing any due to the catch block, but log the error or inspect it in the debugger so you can include the relevant information in your question.

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed my issue. I had a an error in my insert query.

Updated query:

```
insert into tb_uploadedFiles(Name,Type,Data)values(@Name,@Type,@Data
```